# How can I detect when a key has been released (SDL 2.0)

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm having issues detecting when a key has been released. If I were to call:

```
csdl_setup->GetMainEvent()->key.keysym.sym == SDLK_UP
```

SDLK_UP would not be true for around 2-3s which is inefficient for a keyboard driven menu. I want to be able to scroll through my menu easily in SDL.

Can anybody help me?

```
SDL_Event event;
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event) && event.key.repeat == 0 && some_sprite->GetY() == coords[1] && event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
{
    some_sprite->SetY(coords[1] + 20);
}

SDL_PollEvent(&event);
if (event.key.repeat == 0 && some_sprite->GetY() == coords[3])
{

    if(some_sprite->GetY() == coords[3] && event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
    {
        some_sprite->SetY(coords[3] + 20);
    }
    cout << "Event Key Repeat = " << event.key.repeat << endl;

}
```

Comment: Why are you polling all events and then trying to poll it again, and not even checking if polling succeeded? (because it surely isn't - you just poped all events from queue, it is empty).

Comment: Woops, I'll remove that and see what happens, any other suggestions?

Comment: Well, within that simple fragment - no. In general, you should loop over every PollEvent result and check it for everything you want, because you wouldn't get a second chance - once event is polled, it is poped from queue and you can't get it again. Your latest poll almost always did nothing, and `if` was checked on last event you've got. Aside from that, I don't know what your code is doing; don't even know what "main event" supposed to mean.

Comment: Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is to be able to go through a menu via keyboard down/up (but in SDL 2.0, when it detects that keyboard down or up, that event stays true for too long or too many instances, even though I've pressed it once, so it'll usually just go through my menu too much) so I need to find an alternate method.

Comment: If key repeat is disabled, you get only one event for keydown and one for keyup. Delay is of course present, but it miliseconds, not seconds like you say. If it is not the case, you doing something wrong. SDL have literally hundreds shipped titles, it does not suffers from that kind of problems.

Answer (score 2):

You should be handling events as they come.  Your code uses multiple calls to SDL_PollEvent() and even short-circuits the polling in some cases.

Move all of your event handling code into the while loop.  Remove the additional checks on the while loop so you stay in the loop until all events are processed.

A quick modification of your code might look something like this:

```
SDL_Event event;
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
{
    if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if(event.key.repeat == 0)
        {
            if(some_sprite->GetY() == coords[1])
                some_sprite->SetY(coords[1] + 20);
            else if(some_sprite->GetY() == coords[3])
                some_sprite->SetY(coords[3] + 20);
        }
        cout << "Event Key Repeat = " << event.key.repeat << endl;
    }
}
```